# CPU frequency issue: What is idma64.0, and what triggers its hyper-activity?

Tags: cpufreq

Following up on the old question [CPU frequency always at the maximum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905122/cpu-frequency-always-at-the-maximum), I have found that

```
sudo powertop
```

gives a process called `idma64.0` with 300 to 4200 events/second when the CPU frequency is stuck at 3500 MHz, instead of slowing down. When the CPU frequency varies between 600 und 3500 MHz (as it should), the `idma64.0` process can't be seen in `powertop` output. For comparison: When I have several Facebook tabs open in Firefox, `powertop` shows that `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox` is the most taxing process, clocking in at around 200 to 300 events/second.

Well, why is `idma64.0` so active?

Comment: Idma64 is  the core driver for the Intel integrated DMA [1](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/dma/idma64.c).   
And DMA standns for direct memory access [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access).